# What to do after a force push to Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I made the mistake about 3 months ago of doing a force push to Mercurial, and somehow, it has remembered that...so whenever I push now, it forces it by default:

```
% hg --repository C:\Projects\Sonic\DDSF push --force ssh://192.168.52.2:22//hg/DDSF
```

How do I get rid of this setting and go back to the regular pushes?

My team gets mad at me daily because I'm constantly creating new heads and breaking stuff :(

I've checked my `.hgrc` file and its not there. I've also re-installed the TortoiseHg client in hopes that it would solve this problem but it hasn't.

Comment: Have you checked the `.hg/hgrc` file inside the repository? Maybe you added a alias?

Comment: @FaheemMitha yes, i checked that file,  it only has the default ssh url.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In TortoiseHG, you can disable the setting as follows:

1. Go to the "Synchronize" screen via the menu **View** -> **Synchronize** or by clicking this button in the toolbar:
   [image: toolbar]
2. Click the "Options" button under the list of commits:
   [image: options button]
3. In the options window, there's a checkbox for the "force push" setting:
   [image: force push settings]

---

*By the way, when force is enabled, you should already see this below the "Options" button in step two:*
[image]